# Are restaurants required to have a bathroom available?

Tags: canada, business, british-columbia, customer-service, restaurants

In a restaurant:

1. If they have a bathroom, must they let paying or unpaying customers use it?
2. Can they deny use to people who have not bought anything?
3. There's a McDonald's that does not allow use of its bathroom after 11pm. Is this legal?

Comment: What jurisdiction?  Building codes and restaurant inspections are highly localized.

Comment: +1 for the above.  At least in NYC, small restaurants aren't required to have any sort of bathroom.

Comment: @user662852 I didn't mean to ask that, I updated the question

Comment: @SamT What jurisdiction?

Comment: @Mr_Vitale BC, Canada

Comment: "Accessible" is typically read to imply "disabled accessible" - I edited the question bc I don't think it's what you mean

Comment: @jqning I think it rather depends on word order. A requirement to have a bathroom accessible for customers is different from a requirement to have an accessible bathroom.

Comment: I join the chorus that says that this varies considerably by country and somewhat by locality. Usually, there would be a local ordinance governing restaurants and food service (sometimes part of a building or zoning code) that would govern this issue. Denying use of bathrooms to non-customers is routine in most parts of the U.S. I'm not sure what an "unpaying customer" would be. Someone who knows B.C., Canada can say more.

Answer (score 1):

Like the others asked, you need make clear where in the world you are talking about.

My brother owns a bar in London England - My understanding is if you have seats for five or more people, then you must have washrooms during business opening hours.

If the business is closed, or if you are not a customer, they do not have to let you in the premises, let alone let you use their washroom.

Some premises ask non-customers to pay - they can - They are in a service industry, and keeps the facilities clean and/or functional.

Comment: Exception: People with certain disabilities have the right to use his washroom. Or whatever facilities are there if there is no washroom. As long as someone is there who can open the door.